# Manual rotation in matplotlib polygon

Tags: matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
print(mpl.get_backend())

def rotate(xy,deg,rp):
    """xy is the path, deg is degrees of rotation, rp is the rotation point"""
    #translate first, rotate, then retranslate
    xy = xy-rp
    i=0
    while i<len(xy):
        xy[i][0]= xy[i][0]*np.cos(np.deg2rad(deg))-(xy[i][1]*np.sin(np.deg2rad(deg)))
        xy[i][1]= xy[i][0]*np.sin(np.deg2rad(deg))+xy[i][1]*np.cos(np.deg2rad(deg))
        i+=1
    return xy+rp


#fig = plt.figure()
#ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

f,(ax) = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(8,8))
f.subplots_adjust(hspace=0,wspace=0)
ax.set_xlim(0,10)
ax.set_ylim(-2,8)
plt.grid(True)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 10+1, 0.5))
plt.yticks(np.arange(-2, 8+1, 0.5))


def xy(height=1.3,width=2,center=(0,0)):

    num = []
    ran1 = range(0,361)
    b=height#height
    a=width#width
    i=360
    femur_dict = {}
    xcen=center[0]
    ycen=center[1]
    for counter in range(0,360):
        num.append(np.array([a*np.cos(np.deg2rad(counter))+xcen,b*np.sin(np.deg2rad(ran1[counter]))+ycen]))
        i-=1
    return num

scale = 1
t2 = mpl.patches.Polygon(xy(center=(7,7),height=1*scale,width=0.25*scale),fc="blue")
td2dis = ax.transData
coords = td2dis.transform(t2.get_xy()[270])
    #rotate transform
tr = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg_around(coords[0], coords[1], -90)
t = td2dis + tr
t3=mpl.patches.Polygon(t2.get_xy(),fc='green',alpha=0.5,zorder=10000)
t3.set_transform(t)

t4 = mpl.patches.Polygon(rotate(xy(center=(7,7),height=1*scale,width=0.25*scale),45,t2.get_xy()[270]),fc="red")

ax.add_patch(t4)

ax.add_patch(t2)
ax.add_patch(t3)


plt.show()
```

I want to rotate an object manually. I need to access the raw coordinates of an object after applying a transform. How do i access the transformed coordinates of t3?

The red is manual rotation and its not working but the function is coorect. Matplotlib ask too much.
[image: matplotlib is requiring above and beyond what an intuitive rotation should be.]

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have an error in the `rotate` function, because the y coordinate takes the newly calculated x coordinte instead of the original one into account. An easy fix would be

```
def rotate(xy,deg,rp):
    """xy is the path, deg is degrees of rotation, rp is the rotation point"""
    #translate first, rotate, then retranslate
    xy = xy-rp
    i=0
    while i<len(xy):
        a = xy[i][0]*np.cos(np.deg2rad(deg))-(xy[i][1]*np.sin(np.deg2rad(deg)))
        b = xy[i][0]*np.sin(np.deg2rad(deg))+xy[i][1]*np.cos(np.deg2rad(deg))
        xy[i] = [a,b]
        i+=1
    return xy+rp
```

Which would yield

[image]

Second, I think you want to perform the rotation in data space, not in display space. As shown e.g. in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43000288/unable-to-rotate-a-matplotlib-patch-object-about-a-specific-point-using-rotate-d), this would be done by  applying the rotation *before* transforming to display space via `ax.transData`.

So what you probably want is the following:

```
t2 = mpl.patches.Polygon(xy(center=(7,7),height=1,width=0.25),fc="blue")
td2dis = ax.transData
coords = t2.get_xy()[270]

tr = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg_around(coords[0], coords[1], -90)

t3=mpl.patches.Polygon(t2.get_xy(),fc='green',alpha=0.5,zorder=10000)
t3.set_transform(tr + td2dis)

ax.add_patch(t2)
ax.add_patch(t3)
```

Now when you ask for the "raw coordinates" of t3, there are two possibilities,

**Do you mean the data coordinates?**

In this case those are in `tr.transform(t3.get_xy())`, where `tr` is the rotation from above.

**Do you mean the display coordinates?**

Those are in `(tr + td2dis).transform(t3.get_xy())`.

Comment: Great you fixed the function. I didnt notice. Unfortunately neither data coordinates or display coordinates are what I am looking for. Im looking for a function to return the coordinate (9,6) which is the furtherst point on the green oval.

Comment: Could be, because in your question you do not even tell what you are looking for.

Comment: When discussing a image like this its got to be the most intuitive data points on the graph you follow the axis ticks 9 on the x and 6 on the y. you can get the untransformed oval equivalent with get_xy. but on the transformed oval you cant get that point nore can you get it with the data coordinate technique or the display coordinate technique

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `tr.transform(t3.get_xy())` gives you the transformed data.

Comment: tr.transform(t3.get_xy())[0] = array([  -37.        ,  1063.41666667])
I cant find (9,6) in the data set

Comment: No, `print(tr.transform(t3.get_xy())[0])` results in `[ 8.    5.75]`.

Comment: i just dont get that number i get (-37, 1063)