# How to rotate matplotlib.patches.Polygon?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

How to rotate `matplotlib.patches.Polygon`? The output from the code below shows nothing.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib as mpl
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,3))
x = [0.3,0.6,.5,.4]
y = [0.7,0.7,0.9,0.9]

trapezoid = patches.Polygon(xy=list(zip(x,y)), fill=False)

t_start = ax.transData
t = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg(-45)
t_end = t_start + t

trapezoid.set_transform(t_end)

print(repr(t_start))
print(repr(t_end))
ax.add_patch(trapezoid)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you check out posts such as [Unable to rotate a matplotlib patch object about a specific point using rotate_around( )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557608/unable-to-rotate-a-matplotlib-patch-object-about-a-specific-point-using-rotate-a) and [Matplotlib: rotating a patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285103/matplotlib-rotating-a-patch)

Comment: I tried it. I edited the code in my question. What is wrong that the output does not show the rotated object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When composing the tranformations, you must use `t_end = t + t_start` instead of `t_start + t`. The `+` operator is overloaded: `a` + `b` means to first apply `a` and then apply `b`. For affine transformations this means the matrix product `B@A` where `A` and `B` are the transformation matrices of `a` and `b` respectively.  The matrix product is [not commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Non-commutativity).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib as mpl
import copy

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,3))
x = [0.3,0.6,.5,.4]
y = [0.7,0.7,0.9,0.9]

trapezoid = patches.Polygon(xy=list(zip(x,y)), fill=False)
ax.add_patch(copy.copy(trapezoid))

t_start = ax.transData
t = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg(-45)
t_end = t + t_start

trapezoid.set_transform(t_end)
ax.add_patch(trapezoid)

plt.show()
```

[image]