# How can I rotate a matplotlib plot through 90 degrees?

Tags: python, matplotlib, rotation, figure

I have created a figure in matplotlib which contains three subplots, one in the top left quadrant, one in the top right quadrant, and one in the bottom right quadrant. The top right figure contains a two-d image, and the other two plots are the projection onto the Y and X axis respectively. I'd like to rotate the top left quadrant subplot through 90deg counterclockwise, so that the x-axis of that plot lies along the y-axis of the 2-d plot.

For the subplot, I realize I could flip the x and y data, rotate the axis labels, create a plot title on the left hand side, etc. But I was hoping to find a single call which would just rotate the whole, finished plot through 90deg. But I can't find one.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 20):

Another interesting parameter for a lot of functions is `transform` (unlike `orientation` or `pivot` this parameter can also be used in e.g. [`plot`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot)).

The `transform` parameter allows you to add a transformation, specified by a [`Transform`](http://matplotlib.org/api/transformations.html#matplotlib.transforms.Transform) object. For the sake of example, this is how you would rotate the plot of some random data:

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot, transforms

data = numpy.random.randn(100)

# first of all, the base transformation of the data points is needed
base = pyplot.gca().transData
rot = transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg(90)

# define transformed line
line = pyplot.plot(data, 'r--', transform= rot + base)
# or alternatively, use:
# line.set_transform(rot + base)

pyplot.show()
```

For an example on how to rotate a patch, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4891658/4375377), which was also the source of inspiration for this answer.

---

### update

I recently found out that the `transform` parameter does not work as expected when using `pyplot.scatter` (and other `PathCollections`). In this case, you might want to use the `offset_transform`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43915452/4375377) for more information on how to the `offset_transform` can be set.

Comment: I really like this answer - it helped me a lot.

Note that the order of the sum does matter:
`rot + base != base + rot`

Answer (score 19):

Many of the pyplot 1D plots seem to have "orientation" or "pivot" options within their own arguments. For example, from matplotlib.org example of histogram:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.hist(x, 
                       bins=10, 
                       range=None, 
                       normed=False, 
                       weights=None, 
                       cumulative=False, 
                       bottom=None, 
                       histtype=u'bar', 
                       align=u'mid', 
                       orientation=u'vertical', 
                       rwidth=None, 
                       log=False, 
                       color=None, 
                       label=None, 
                       stacked=False, 
                       hold=None, 
                       **kwargs)
```

Just change to horizontal (`orientation=u'vertical'`)

Comment: But why does matplotlib flip the coordinates by 90 degrees before plotting

Answer (score 7):

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig=plt.figure() 
ax=fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')

# for rotate the axes and update.
for angle in range(0,360): 
    ax.view_init(30,angle)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Main Code :-

ax.view_init(-30, -90)

Answer (score 1):

It is simple if you just want to get a view of a rotated plot without proper coordinates:

1. Swap axis (x, y) of scatter/plot data: (y, x).
2. Changing sign of y to negative (-y, x) rotates plot 90 degree clockwise

Say, we have initial data:

```
x_coordinates = np.array([351,345,339,336,333,330,327,324,318,312])
y_coordinates = np.array([84, 84, 83, 82, 81, 80, 80, 79, 78, 77])
```

Its plot `plt.plot(x_coordinates,y_coordinates)` is:
[image]

plt.plot(-y_coordinates,x_coordinates) will rotate 90 counterclockwise:
[image]

By swap and sign change you can not only rotate, but also flip the plot. **Again, here the plot axes will not be shown correct.**

Comment: dead link there :(

Comment: I removed dead link posed before for reference and instantiated solution

Comment: Thanks. About the solution, this is the approach I took. However I found out a mistake. You see there you are not rotating. The original X became the Y but the original Y went Horizontal with the opposite sign. (77-> -77) It is not big if you are making a draft, but when other people are involved, they notice that as a defect. So this is not a complete solution

Comment: @KansaiRobot That is right, someone needs more than just a new plot view, but  coordinates as well.