# Matplotlib 2D plot vertical x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was wondering if there is a **quick** way to have, in a 2D plot, the x-axis oriented vertically, from top to bottom. I am looking for the Matlab equivalent of

```
 set(gca,'view',[90,90])
```

if any.

The only solution I found is [How can I rotate a matplotlib plot through 90 degrees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22540449/how-can-i-rotate-a-matplotlib-plot-through-90-degrees)
but I cannot make in work because I have several plots on the figure

Answer (score 0):

One way you could accomplish this is just to swap the X, Y values you pass to the function.  For example, if you have lists of X values and Y values (the points are (X[i], Y[i]), you could just do:

```
scatter(Y,X)
```

instead of

```
scatter(X,Y)
```

Comment: The x-axis in this case will still point from the origin upward, not from the top down.  I just re-read your post and I see you may have been looking for that.  You can accomplish the "down" pointing by multiplying all your X-values by -1 (and doing the reverse mentioned here).

Comment: I thought about it..only it seems weird to me that matplotlib is missing such a basic feature

Comment: I cannot accomplish the downward pointing as you suggested because I need to have a logarithmic x-axis, so I cannot negate the values @TravisJ

Comment: The best I can do is
`plot(y,-log(x))`

Comment: You could negate the x-values then translate them upwards (so that the smallest one is still greater than 0).  For example, if your x-range is -10 to 100, multiplying by -1 gives a range of -100 to 10, then shift everything up by say 101, so you have a range of 1 to 111.