# transform entire axes (or scatter plot) in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, transform

I am plotting changes in mean and variance of some data with the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import numpy

vis_mv(data, ax = None):
    if ax is None: ax = pyplot.gca()
    cmap = pyplot.get_cmap()
    colors = cmap(numpy.linspace(0, 1, len(data)))

    xs = numpy.arange(len(data)) + 1
    means = numpy.array([ numpy.mean(x) for x in data ])
    varis = numpy.array([ numpy.var(x) for x in data ])
    vlim = max(1, numpy.amax(varis))

    # variance
    ax.imshow([[0.,1.],[0.,1.]],
        cmap = cmap, interpolation = 'bicubic',
        extent = (1, len(data), -vlim, vlim), aspect = 'auto'
    )
    ax.fill_between(xs, -vlim, -varis, color = 'white')
    ax.fill_between(xs, varis, vlim, color = 'white')

    # mean
    ax.plot(xs, means, color = 'white', zorder = 1)
    ax.scatter(xs, means, color = colors, edgecolor = 'white', zorder = 2)
    
    return ax
```

This works perfectly fine:
[image]
but now I would like to be able to use this visualisation also in a vertical fashion as some kind of advanced color bar kind of thingy next to another plot. I hoped it would be possible to rotate the entire axis with all of its contents,
but I could only find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22540449/how-can-i-rotate-a-matplotlib-plot-through-90-degrees), which does not really have a solid answer yet either. Therefore, I tried to do it myself as follows:

```
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D

ax = vis_mv()
r = Affine2D().rotate_deg(90) + ax.transData

for x in ax.images + ax.lines + ax.collections:
    x.set_transform(r)

old = ax.axis()
ax.axis(old[2:4] + old[0:2])
```

This **almost** does the trick (note how the scattered points, which used to lie along the white line, are blown up and not rotated as expected).
[image]
Unfortunately the `PathCollection` holding the result of the `scatter`ing does not act as expected. After trying out some things, I found that scatter has some kind of *offset transform*, which seems to be the equivalent of the *regular transform* in other collections.

```
x = numpy.arange(5)
ax = pyplot.gca()
p0, = ax.plot(x)
p1 = ax.scatter(x,x)

ax.transData == p0.get_transform()           # True
ax.transData == p1.get_offset_transform()    # True
```

It seems like I might want to change the offset transform instead for the scatter plot, but I did not manage to find any method that allows me to change that transform on a `PathCollection`. Also, it would make it a lot more inconvenient to do what I actually want to do.

Would anyone know if there exists a possibility to change the offset transform?

Comment: Can you post a sample image of what you have, and (approximately) what you want?

Comment: @VBB Is it more clear now?

Comment: How about just plotting everything vertically to begin with? `imshow`, `scatter` and `plot` will work as is, and you could use `ax.fill_betweenx` for the coloring. (PS: nice trick for shading)

Comment: @VBB I originally did everything vertically (except that I did not know of `ax.fill_betweenx`), but in order to have a closer look I rewrote my code to be horizontal in the hope that I would be able to rotate the entire thing. I could obviously have two functions, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I rotate a matplotlib plot through 90 degrees?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22540449/how-can-i-rotate-a-matplotlib-plot-through-90-degrees)

Comment: Why do you mark this as duplicate if this question explicitely asks about something the linked question does not ask about?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest The original reason why I ask this question was exactly because I want to rotate an entire plot 90 degrees. Therefore I thought it might make sense to merge these questions. I also feel somehow stupid for having answered that question before asking this one.

Comment: Yes but here you ask specifically about a problem that arises when using one of the solutions (doesn't matter who wrote them) of the other answer. So it definitely makes sense to link them, but I would not consider this to be a duplicate.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I updated my question to     
1) mention the existence of the other question
2) focus on the scatter plot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately the `PathCollection` does not have a `.set_offset_transform()` method, but one can access the private `_transOffset` attribute and set the rotating transformation to it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D
from matplotlib.collections import PathCollection
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(3)

def vis_mv(data, ax = None):
    if ax is None: ax = plt.gca()
    cmap = plt.get_cmap()
    colors = cmap(np.linspace(0, 1, len(data)))

    xs = np.arange(len(data)) + 1
    means = np.array([ np.mean(x) for x in data ])
    varis = np.array([ np.var(x) for x in data ])
    vlim = max(1, np.amax(varis))

    # variance
    ax.imshow([[0.,1.],[0.,1.]],
        cmap = cmap, interpolation = 'bicubic',
        extent = (1, len(data), -vlim, vlim), aspect = 'auto'  )
    ax.fill_between(xs, -vlim, -varis, color = 'white')
    ax.fill_between(xs, varis, vlim, color = 'white')

    # mean
    ax.plot(xs, means, color = 'white', zorder = 1)
    ax.scatter(xs, means, color = colors, edgecolor = 'white', zorder = 2)

    return ax

data = np.random.normal(size=(9, 9))
ax  = vis_mv(data)


r = Affine2D().rotate_deg(90)

for x in ax.images + ax.lines + ax.collections:
    trans = x.get_transform()
    x.set_transform(r+trans)
    if isinstance(x, PathCollection):
        transoff = x.get_offset_transform()
        x._transOffset = r+transoff

old = ax.axis()
ax.axis(old[2:4] + old[0:2])


plt.show()
```

[image]