# Adjusting the position of a matplotlib floating axis in a subplot, and reversing an axis direction

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

This question leads on from a previous question I asked yesterday that got me most of the way to what I am after: 
[Rotate transformation on matplotlib axis in subplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52191695/)

I want to create a two by two array of graphs where the bottom-left is a scatter plot and the other three are histograms projecting the x, y, and x-y data from that plot. That final histogram I want to have at a 45 degree angle, and it is the positioning of that plot which I am trying to adjust.

Currently, I have this:

```
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist.floating_axes as floating_axes
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def setup_axes(fig, rect, rotation, axisScale, axisLimits, doShift):
    tr_rot = Affine2D().scale(axisScale[0], axisScale[1]).rotate_deg(rotation)

    # This seems to do nothing
    if doShift:
        tr_trn = Affine2D().translate(-90,-5)
    else:
        tr_trn = Affine2D().translate(0,0)

    tr = tr_rot + tr_trn

    grid_helper = floating_axes.GridHelperCurveLinear(tr, extremes=axisLimits)

    ax = floating_axes.FloatingSubplot(fig, rect, grid_helper=grid_helper)
    fig.add_subplot(ax)
    aux_ax = ax.get_aux_axes(tr)

    return ax, aux_ax

fig  = plt.figure(1, figsize=(8, 8))
axes = []
axisOrientation = [0, 0, 270, -45]
axisScale = [[1,1],[6,1],[6,1],[6,1]]
axisPosition = [223,221,224,222]
axisLimits = [(-0.5, 4.5, -0.5, 4.5),
              (-0.5, 4.5, 0, 12),
              (-0.5, 4.5, 0, 12),
              (-3.5, 3.5, 0, 12)]
doShift = [False, False, False, True]

label_axes = []
for i in range(0, len(axisOrientation)):
    ax, aux_ax = setup_axes(fig, axisPosition[i], axisOrientation[i], 
                            axisScale[i], axisLimits[i], doShift[i])
    axes.append(aux_ax)
    label_axes.append(ax)

numPoints = 100
x = []
y = []
for i in range(0,numPoints):
    x.append(np.random.rand() + i/100.0)
    y.append(np.random.rand() + i/100.0 + np.mod(i,2)*2)

axes[0].plot(x,y,ls='none',marker='x')
label_axes[0].axis["bottom"].label.set_text('Variable 1')
label_axes[0].axis["left"].label.set_text('Variable 2')

b = np.linspace(-0.5,4.5,50)
axes[1].hist(x, bins = b)
axes[2].hist(y, bins = b)
b = np.linspace(-3.5,3.5,50)
axes[3].hist(np.array(x)-np.array(y), bins=b)

for i in range(1,len(label_axes)):
    for axisLoc in ['top','left','right']:
        label_axes[i].axis[axisLoc].set_visible(False)
    label_axes[i].axis['bottom'].toggle(ticklabels=False)    

fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=-0.30, hspace=-0.30, left=0.00, right=0.99, top=0.99, bottom=0.0)
plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image]

As you can see in the code, I try to shift the position of that top-right plot with an `Affine2D().translate()` but it seems to have no effect. Does anybody know how I might move this plot so that its x-axis almost-touches the top-right corner of the bottom-left plot's axes?

**Edit:**

I have also just noticed that the bottom-right plot is upside-down compared to how it should be. It needs to be top-bottom mirrored somehow.

**Edit 2:**

This code before fig.subplots_adjust() will fix that:
`label_axes[2].invert_yaxis()`