# Flip vertical bar plot over X axis Altair

Tags: python, altair

If I have this bar plot:

[image]

How can I flip it like this

[image]

Of course preserving right labels.

Comment: Do you just want to rotate the picture itself? That can be done in paint or similar. Or are you asking for something else?

Comment: I want the bar bins to start from the right

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22540449/how-can-i-rotate-a-matplotlib-plot-through-90-degrees

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by swapping the `x` and `y` encodings and adjusting the axis properties accordingly. For example, if you have this chart:

```python
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1701)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'data': 6 + np.random.randn(500)
})

alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('data', bin=alt.Bin(maxbins=40)),
    y='count()'
).properties(width=800, height=150)
```

[image]

You can create a rotated version like this:

```python
alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    y=alt.Y('data', bin=alt.Bin(maxbins=40), axis=alt.Axis(orient='right')),
    x=alt.X('count()', scale=alt.Scale(reverse=True))
).properties(width=150, height=800)
```

[image]