# Rotate plot in matplotlib figure by 90 degree

Tags: python, matplotlib, rotation, figure

I am trying to rotate plot inside matplotlib figure by 90 degree.
I found out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22540449/how-can-i-rotate-a-matplotlib-plot-through-90-degrees#answer-42978441) but it uses pyplot and I am using simple plot so that does not work, Also he doesn't explain the code for rotating pyplot but mentions **transform property** can also be used to rotate simple plot graph. I tried searching online for transformation tutorial but could not understand the concept.

Here is me code snippet

```py
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy

# random data
data = numpy.random.randn(100)

# making figure on which plot will be draw
fig = Figure(figsize=(11, 8),dpi=100)
# adding plot to figure
plot1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
# plotting values
plot1.plot(data)

# saving figure for later use
fig.savefig("graph.jpeg")
```

It produces following result;

[image: current output]

But I want this kind of output;

[image: required output]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To rotate graph you can use this trick by changing axis `(x, y) -> (y, x)` and rotate current `x-axis`:

```
x = numpy.arange(100)
data = numpy.random.randn(100)
plot1.plot(-data, x)
```

Comment: This trick worked for me ... cheers!
only thing I have to change was the - operand with data as I am not working with numpy array but python list 
So I used list comprehension to achieve it 
`data = [ -x for x in data]`