# How can you rotate a barplot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been going off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22540449/how-can-i-rotate-a-matplotlib-plot-through-90-degrees) which said to use orientation=u'horizontal', so I made this simple code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.bar(x=[1,2,3],
        height=[1,2,3],
        orientation=u'horizontal')
plt.show()
```

But I get the error:
`TypeError: the dtypes of parameters y (object) and height (int64) are incompatible`.

Why is that? Is it because I am specifically rotating a barplot?

P.S. I tried specifying y, even though I'm not sure it is appropriate in a barplot. That also gave an error.

Comment: Maybe use `barh`?  Or `plt.barh(y=[1,2,3], width=[1,2,3])`

Comment: You should post this as an answer it works

Comment: That being said do you know why my code doesn't work? Is it a bug with matplotlib?

Comment: I don't know what version of matplotlib you are using, seems like the term **orientation** is not a parameter of bar plot. [here] (https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html). When you remove it from the expression, the code runs fine.  For horizontal as mentioned above do use barh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the link you provided is 7 years old

in an oler version of matplotlib 2.1.0 it says about orientation as a parameter and says

**orientation** : {‘vertical’, ‘horizontal’}, optional

This is **for internal use, please do not directly use this**, call **barh instead**.

https://matplotlib.org/2.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html