# Is it possible to make a Cartopy projection where north is NOT facing up?

Tags: python, matplotlib, transform, projection, cartopy

I'm trying to make a plot of the earth in geocentric solar ecliptic coordinates. This is a coordinate system centered at the earth's center and where +x points towards the sun, +z is parallel to the north ecliptic pole (aka, normal to the plane in which the earth orbits the sun), and +y is towards dusk.

To do this, I'm calculating the subsolar point and using that to find the point on the earth's surface (in latitude/longitude) that lines up with the Z axis. Then I'm making an orthographic projection of the Earth using cartopy, centered at the calculated latitude and longitude.

[This is the graph I'm creating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVAcf.png)

I'm centering the map at the correct location. However, the problem is that I can't figure out how to rotate the map in two dimensions left and right. The only keywords the projection takes are central_longitude, central_latitude, and globe. There's nothing to tell it which way to rotate. It seems like cartopy only allows maps to be made so north is facing up, but I need to rotate the map sideways so the sun is facing the right side instead of the bottom.

Here's the code to generate that plot:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,9))
t = dt.datetime(2014,12,30,0,0,0)
subsolar_lat, subsolar_long = sun_pos(t)

# Center at north ecliptic pole (GSE)
proj_long = subsolar_long  
proj_lat = 90-abs(subsolar_lat) 
proj=ccrs.Orthographic(proj_long, proj_lat) 
left, bottom, width, height = [0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5] 
ax = fig.add_axes([left, bottom, width, height], projection = proj)

# Make the map look good 
ax.gridlines()
ax.set_global()
ax.set_title(f"{t}")
ax.coastlines()
ax.add_feature(cf.OCEAN, alpha=0.2)
ax.add_feature(cf.LAND, alpha=0.5)
fill_dark_side(ax, time=t, color='black', alpha=0.5)
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71474325/rotating-cartopy-map-by-90-degrees) question on StackOverflow which seems to be exactly what I'm trying to do. However, no one answered it, and their edit doesn't really solve my question either.

I've also tried a few different ways to rotate the axis, but none of them seem to work with Cartopy.

Is there a way to apply a transformation to this projection or to rotate an axis that uses Cartopy?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate the whole axis, matpltolib's `floating_axes` might help?

https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/axisartist/demo_floating_axes.html

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21654433/9703451