# Fill between two vertical lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

I went through the [examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/fill_between_demo.html) in the `matplotlib` documentation, but it wasn't clear to me how I can make a plot that fills the area between two specific vertical lines.

For example, say I want to create a plot between `x=0.2` and `x=4` (for the full `y` range of the plot). Should I use `fill_between`, `fill` or `fill_betweenx`?

Can I use the `where` condition for this?

Answer (score 316, accepted):

It sounds like you want [`axvspan`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvspan.html), rather than one of the fill between functions. The differences is that `axvspan` (and [`axhspan`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axhspan.html)) will fill up the entire y (or x) extent of the plot regardless of how you zoom.

For example, let's use `axvspan` to highlight the x-region between 8 and 14:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(20))
ax.axvspan(8, 14, alpha=0.5, color='red')

plt.show()
```

[image]

You could use `fill_betweenx` to do this, but the extents (both x and y) of the rectangle would be in *data coordinates*.  With `axvspan`, the y-extents of the rectangle default to 0 and 1 and are in *axes coordinates* (in other words, percentages of the height of the plot).

To illustrate this, let's make the rectangle extend from 10% to 90% of the height (instead of taking up the full extent).  Try zooming or panning, and notice that the y-extents say fixed in display space, while the x-extents move with the zoom/pan:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(20))
ax.axvspan(8, 14, ymin=0.1, ymax=0.9, alpha=0.5, color='red')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: people who are interested in a solution to use `fill_between` for more "wiggly", vertical lines, have a look at the `transform` parameter (and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4891658/4375377))

Comment: It seems that `axvspan` add some contour around the bands (you can see it in your figure). Can it be removed?

Comment: In case it helps someone else, just add `linewidth=0` to the `axvspan` call.