# How do I fill between two curves defined by two different sets of arrays?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two curves defined by two sets of arrays: `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)` and I want to fill between them with polygons. All arrays are the same length but `x1` and `x2` contain different values.

`plt.fill_between(x, y1, y2)` requires that both curves share the same x-array.

How do I do something like `fill_between(x1, y1, x2, y2)`?

For instance if:

`x1 = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0])` and `y1 = np.array([3.0, 2.0, 3.0, 2.0, 3.0])` define the first curve

and

`x2 = np.array([1.5, 2.5 ,3.5 ,4.5 , 5.5])` and `y2 = np.array([5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0])` define the second.

How can I fill colour between curves `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)` using four polygons (the left and right boundaries need not be vertical)?

To clarify, the four polygons (A,B,C,D) would have coordinates:

```
A: [(1.0, 3.0), (1.5, 5.0), (2.5, 6.0), (2.0, 2.0)]
B: [(2.0, 2.0), (2.5, 6.0), (3.5, 7.0), (3.0, 3.0)]
C: [(3.0, 3.0), (3.5, 7.0), (4.5, 8.0), (4.0, 2.0)]
D: [(4.0, 2.0), (4.5, 8.0), (5.5, 9.0), (5.0, 3.0)]
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Currently your question is too broad. Provide some code and data to get concrete help. You can use some sort of interpolation on your x arrays but as I said, without having a look at the data, it's hard to tell anything

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to clarify what I'm trying to do.

Comment: How many polygons? What points define the polygon boundaries? Do you want the vertical fills because your starting and end x points are different for both curves? You have to clarify these questions. Include a sample desired figure in the question

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23248435/fill-between-two-vertical-lines-in-matplotlib) post, should answer your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm struggling to interpret your question unambiguously, but I think you just want to use `fill`, something like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0])
y1 = np.array([3.0, 2.0, 3.0, 2.0, 3.0])

x2 = np.array([1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5])
y2 = np.array([5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0])

plt.plot(x1, y1, 'o')
plt.plot(x2, y2, 'x')

plt.fill(
    np.append(x1, x2[::-1]),
    np.append(y1, y2[::-1]),
)
```

would give you

[image: this plot]

Comment: Hi @Sam, I have a similar problem, but in my case x1,y1 is a curve which has a color (let's say red), and x2 and y2 is another curve with a different color (let's say blue.) I want to fill the area with a gradient that goes from red (first curve) to blue (second curve).

How can I do this? I have tried several ways but without any success.

Comment: @OscarGabrielReyesPupo that sounds mostly unrelated to this question.. I'd suggest searching around for something closer, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/29321835/1358308 or posting a separate question with more details if you're stills tuck

Comment: thanks. I have posted this question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63810793/filling-the-area-between-archimedes-spyrals-with-interpolated-colours-matplotl/63811472#63811472

Answer (score 2):

You can use polygonal patches do draw quadrilaterals filling the space between the two curves — the only tricky point is the generation of the 5 points that define the polygon but (ab)using `zip` it can be done... also you need to know how to place the polygons on the plot, but it's easy when you know of `matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection` and `ax.add_collection`

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

x1 = np.linspace(0,6,21) ; y1 = np.sin(x1)
x2 = x1+0.28 ; y2 = np.cos(x2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()                                                         
ax.plot(x1, y1, x2, y2)
patches = [Polygon(poly) for poly in (
              [p0,p1,p2,p3,p0] for p0,p1,p2,p3 in 
                    zip(zip(x1,y1),zip(x1[1:],y1[1:]),zip(x2[1:],y2[1:]),zip(x2,y2)))
ax.add_collection(PatchCollection(patches, alpha=0.6))
```

[image: a sample plot]

As you can see, it's not *perfect* but maybe it's good enough...