# Filling the area between Archimedes spyrals with interpolated colours - Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, spiral

I want to plot various spirals like the ones shown in the Figure (one spiral inner the others). Let's say I have three spirals (S1, S2 and S3) and I want to fill the area between consecutive spirals, i.e. the area between S1 and S2, S2 and S3 and finally between S3 and S1.

[image: Three spirals]

I have tried several ways to solve the following two problems but without any success:

1- The area between a pair of spirals should be painted with interpolated colours. For example, the first spiral (S1) is black and the second one (S2) is gray, then the area between S1 and S2 must be a gradient that goes from black to gray.

2- The area between S3 and S1 has not being filled as I want. Here, the area filled is between S1 and S3, not between S3 and S1.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def create_archimides_spiral(a=0, b=1, num_spirals=10):

    """
    Functions that creates an archimides spiral
    """

    th = np.linspace(0, num_spirals*np.pi, num_spirals*100) # The higher the number of splits, the greater the quality of each segment

    r = a + b*th

    x = r * np.cos(th)
    y = r * np.sin(th)

    return x, y

# create the spirals
x, y = create_archimides_spiral(a=0,b=1)
x1, y1 = create_archimides_spiral(a=2, b=1)
x2, y2 = create_archimides_spiral(a=4, b=1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(x, y, color='black', linewidth=3)
ax.plot(x1, y1, color='gray', linewidth=3)
ax.plot(x2, y2, color='silver', linewidth=3)

plt.fill(
    np.append(x, x1[::-1]),
    np.append(y, y1[::-1]), color= "lightgray"
)

plt.fill(
   np.append(x1, x2[::-1]),
   np.append(y1, y2[::-1]), color= "lightgray"
)

plt.fill_between(x, y, y1, interpolate=True)
plt.fill_between(x1, y, y1, interpolate=True)

ax.set_aspect(1)
plt.show()
```

This is the figure that I obtained, but this is not that I want.

[image: Filled areas]

I would appreciate any help on this.

Best regrads

Oscar

Answer (score 3):

I get a solution for filling properly between S1 and S3. As for the gradient, `fill_btween` or `fill_betweenx` require either same set of x or y, which is not your case. For gradient, @JohanC 's approximation is nice.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def create_archimides_spiral(a=0, b=1, num_spirals=10):

    """
    Functions that creates an archimides spiral
    """

    th = np.linspace(0, num_spirals*np.pi, num_spirals*100) # The higher the number of splits, the greater the quality of each segment

    r = a + b*th

    x = r * np.cos(th)
    y = r * np.sin(th)

    return x, y, r

# create the spirals
x, y, r= create_archimides_spiral(a=0,b=1)
x1, y1, r1 = create_archimides_spiral(a=2, b=1)
x2, y2, r2 = create_archimides_spiral(a=4, b=1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(x, y, color='black', linewidth=3)
ax.plot(x1, y1, color='gray', linewidth=3)
ax.plot(x2, y2, color='silver', linewidth=3)

ax.fill_between(np.concatenate((x, x1[::-1])), np.concatenate((y, y1[::-1])), color= "red", interpolate=True)

ax.fill(np.concatenate((x1, x2[::-1])), np.concatenate((y1, y2[::-1])), color= "blue")

ax.fill(np.concatenate([x[::-1], x2[0:800]]), np.concatenate([y[::-1], y2[0:800]]), color= "cyan")

ax.set_aspect(1)
```

You have to be careful about constructing the polygon to fill, only part of x2 and y2 are selected.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could draw many spirals close to each other, in the range from 0 to 2 pi.  (2 pi is the distance between the successive rings.)

Note that a color value as `'0.20'` (a string of a number) corresponds to a grey value of `0.20`, where `0` is black and `1` is white.

Also note that `plt.fill_between()` supposes the x-values are ordered, which isn't the case.

To obtain a fully filled spiral, you could add a start angle to your equation as shown in the central subplot. The right subplot uses an interpolation between two colors.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def create_archimides_spiral(a=0, b=1, start_angle=0, num_spirals=10):
    th = np.linspace(0, num_spirals * np.pi, num_spirals * 100)
    r = a + b * th
    x = r * np.cos(th + start_angle)
    y = r * np.sin(th + start_angle)
    return x, y


fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3)
for ax, largest_a in zip(axes, [2 * np.pi, 2 * np.pi, 1.5 * np.pi]):
    a_values = np.linspace(0, largest_a, 100)
    grey_values = np.linspace(0, 0.8 if ax == axes[0] else 1, 100)
    if ax == axes[1]:
        cmap = plt.cm.inferno
    elif ax == axes[2]:
        cmap = plt.cm.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', ['crimson', 'skyblue'])
    for a, grey in zip(a_values, grey_values):
        if ax == axes[1]:
            x, y = create_archimides_spiral(a=0, b=1, start_angle=a)
        else:
            x, y = create_archimides_spiral(a=a, b=1, start_angle=0)
        ax.plot(x, y, color=f'{grey:.3f}' if ax == axes[0] else cmap(grey))
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image: comparing three plots]

Comment: Thank so much @JohanC, your solution approximates very well what I want! 

I think that I can adapte this solution to my problem. In my case, I have several inner spirals which each one represents something different and, therefore, each spiral can have a different color, for example one red spiral and a blue spiral, and then the area between them goes from red to blue.

Comment: I added an example interpolating between two arbitrary colors.

Comment: By the way, an alternative way to create the spirals till the center is starting theta at `-a/b`: `th = np.linspace(-a/b, num_spirals * np.pi, num_spirals * 100)`. That way the two types of plot can be combined.